# Check if a button is pressed and then check again

Tags: android, if-statement, button, switch-statement

I am rather new to android developing and can't figure out how to do a double check on a button press.
I am working in Android Studio and am trying to create a little simple game and have the following: two buttons (button1 and button2)declared and instantiated in an onClick method.
When button 1 is pressed a counter is incremented and a specific value is shown on the button from an array with the values 0, 10, 50, 100.
This part works like a charm. What I can't do is create a working "tiebreaker rule" which should be something like:

```
if (button1 value == 100 and button2 value == 100) or this can be done with the counter if (counter1 == 3 && counter2 == 3)
tiebreaker();
```

this is what I need to do:

```
public void tiebreaker(){
if (button1 is pressed){
   button1.setText(String.valueOf("OK. One more!");
   if (button1 is pressed (again){
       resetCounters();
       goForPlayer1(); //distinct method
   } else if (button2 is pressed) {
       //set both values back to 100
       tiebreaker(); //calls itself in order to repeat until a button is pressed twice consecutivelly
} (else?)
if(button2 is presed){
//same code as above, just with the numbers 1 and 2 swapped
}
}
```

I have tried implementing this tiebreaker method in different ways, but with no final success. I tried with `if(button1.isPressed())` as condintion, having a boolean turn true when the button is pressed and using it as a condition, using the values from the buttons with `button.equals("100") or whatever should be written` but nothing.

Also, I tried making the tiebreaker as a second onClick method and doing checks based on `switch (View.getId())` but the problem here is that the method being view dependant (`tiebreaker(View v)`) I am not sure how to call it from a different method.

IMO the main issue is that if within another if or switch/case within another switch/case can't be used when it comes to button presses (I could be wrong, though), but I don't know of any other way to do this.

I hope I did not miss anything and managed to make myself clear. 
I appreciate any input in helping me solve this tiebreaker rule. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's *probably* something like this ...

```
whenButtonAIsPressed() {

    do some stuff
    possiblyRunTiebreakerMaterial()
}

whenButtonBIsPressed() {

    do some stuff
    possiblyRunTiebreakerMaterial()
}
```

Note that you ***always*** run `possiblyRunTiebreakerMaterial()` and you ***always*** run it at the *end* of doing all your other processing.

Here's the nature of your `possiblyRunTiebreakerMaterial()` function...

```
possiblyRunTiebreakerMaterial() {

    // there are some conditions, which mean you DO want
    // to run the tie breaker:
    do some processing, such as
    value of A = blah blah
    value of B = blah blah

    // now have a boolean, and figure it out
    boolean  shouldWeRunTheTieBreaker

    processing
    processing
    shouldWeRunTheTieBreaker = blah

    and now finally:
    is shouldWeRunTheTieBreaker == true { tiebreaker() }
}
```

and then have your `tiebreaker()` function.

What you're really looking for is a state machine, but don't worry about that for now.

The general "programming trick" you're looking for here is that you must do these things:

1. **always** do your processing
2. then, only **afterwards**,
3. in **all** cases, check **IF** you need to run the tiebreaker
4. **run** it if needed

That's the pattern.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

The issue I have is not checking if the tiebreaker should be called or not, but the interior of the method itself. At the moment I have no other idea about what to write inside the tiebreaker in order for it to do what I described above.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, I don't have the rating to upvote.
I managed to resolve the issue. Instead of a function, I created a **boolean** for tiebreaker and it looks something like:

```
if (p1 = 100 || p2 == 100)
   tiebreak = true;
if (p1 == 100 && tiebreaker){
   p1 == OK;
   tiebreaker = false;
} else //same thing for p2
```